# Symfony 2 - Generate calendar month table with links to events in it

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an Entity called `Event`, with fields `startDate`, `startTime`, `endDate` and `endTime`. `startDate` and `endDate` are dates of which `endDate` can be NULL if it is the same of `startTime` (I can change this behaviour if it makes things easier as I have no events yet). `startTime` and `endTime` can not be NULL. It also has an `isOnDate(\DateTime $date)` method, which returns `true` if the event will run on the given date.

It was like pain, but I finally generated an HTML table of any given calendar month, passing the day of week of the month's first day (`firstDow`) and the number of days in that month (`numDays`) as template variables.

The next step would be to make some table cells links to event or event listing pages if the given days has one or more events. Now I'm a bit stuck, as I don't know how to get the DateTime() object of each cell in a template.

Can someone give me a hint on this? Or am I making it totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can display DateTime Objects as Text Dates using Twig Filter date:

```
{{ event.startDate|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Comment: That's not really an issue, as I don't have to display any data of the Event objects, but generate a link if the given day has any events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax and jQuery to link dynamically your page with your database. You could start from this calendar code for Symfony2: http://www.symfocal.com